# codeigniter - pass messages to view

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

I am new to codeigniter. I have a controller `users` which loads a `login` view.

```
class user extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form'));
    }
    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->model('user_images');
        $data = $this->load->model('login');
        $this->load->view('login', $data);
    }
}
```

In the `login` model I handle all the validation and processing. If there is a validation error or the like I return `$data['msg'] = 'some error message';` I pass this data via `$data = $this->load->model('login');` to `$this->load->view('login', $data);` and in view I echo `$msg`. However upon submission the form processes, if I enter the correct credentials I get logged in, however if I enter some wrong credentials the validation errors do not get passed to the view. I am moving this project over from an non-framework environment, so I am sure that the validation rules work .etc. I am just not sure why the messages are not getting parsed on the view.

Comment: if you are using codeigniter then use code igniter form validation - it greatly simplifies the messaging for errors. and for forms that fail validation - it can insert the previous form values.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are getting this wrong

```
 $data = $this->load->model('login');
```

The **load->model()** loads the login_model and makes it methods available via

$this->login->youMethodHere().

> f there is a validation error or the like I return $data['msg'] = 'some error message'; I pass this data via $data = $this->load->model('login'); to $this->load->view('login', $data);

When you return something from a method/function you do not return the variable. You return the value of the variable.

You should add you method to the login_model (perhaps this should be user_model...) and return ex. an array or mysqli result set from the model. Depeanding on what the models returns you should set the data.

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
$login_succes = $this->user_model->login($username, $password);
if( $login_success ) 
{
   $data['msg'] = 'hurrah you did it
   ...
```

Comment: so theres no way I can access the error variable from the class because in my constructer i handle everything i want to handle, otherwise i would have to move the constructor materials into the controller? i would really like to not have to rewrite this... http://ideone.com/Ji4oVd... previously instead of `data['msg']` returns i would do `$this->error` and get the error. can i do anything like that?

Comment: Sure, If we are talking the form validation, you could use the validation_errors() or you could return an object/array that has the error msg as a member or you could throw an exception and handle it.
The code you have linked has alot of stuff that does not fit the mvc profile. Like redirection from the model etc.
You should read up on MVC pattern and/or CodeIgniters.